# Error: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I keep getting the mapping exception error for a many to many project I'm trying to create. I have already tried everything that I found in previous answers on StackOverflow.  I have also tried downloading a more recent version of hibernate.

Here are my models for Products and Categories.  Please, if anyone has any idea of what I'm doing wrong.  Please let me know.

PRODUCT MODEL

```
package com.cheryl.productgroups.models;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.management.relation.Role;
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private float price;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class)
    @JoinTable(
      name = "categories_products", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"), 
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    )

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate(){
            this.createdAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate(){
            this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    private List<Category> categories;

    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(String name, String description, float price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.createdAt = new Date();
        this.updatedAt = new Date();    
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}
```

CATEGORY MODEL

```
package com.cheryl.productgroups.models;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.management.relation.Role;
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class)
    @JoinTable(
      name = "categories_products", 
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"), 
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    )

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate(){
            this.createdAt = new Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void onUpdate(){
            this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

    private List<Product> products;

    public Category() {

    }

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.createdAt = new Date();
        this.updatedAt = new Date();    
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you annotating with @ManyToMany the onCreate method instead of the getProducts and getCategories ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are annotating the `onCreate` method with `@ManyToMany`.

Only class fields can be mapped, either by annotating the `field` directly or annotating its `getter` method.

And don't mix both `field` level and `accessors` level mapping, if you decided to choose one of them then do it with all your fields.

So in your case use the `@ManyToMany` and the relative annotations with the `categories` list:

```
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class)
@JoinTable(
  name = "categories_products", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
)
private List<Category> categories;
```

Answer (score 0):

anotate your many to many join on List variable of categories